# How to pass setColor parameter from String

Tags: java, android, hex

I've got a function that receives a String as a parameter called 'color'. color is something like "FFF267". Now I want to do drawable.setColor(0xF0FFF267).How can I do this?
I've tried the following but it throws an exception.

```
   ImageView circ = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle);
   GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) circ.getDrawable();
   drawable.setColor(0xF0 + Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(color)));
```

Comment: see `Color#parseColor`

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 3):

Use this

> Color.parseColor("yourcolorstring");

Comment: Then how should I build my colorstring? 'Cause I'm getting an exception when I put "0xF0FFF267"

Comment: What kind of exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom method like so:

```
    public Color StringToColor(String colorString) {
        return new Color(
        Integer.valueOf( colorStrstring.substring( 1, 3 ), 16 ),
        Integer.valueOf( colorStrstring.substring( 3, 5 ), 16 ),
        Integer.valueOf( colorStrstring.substring( 5, 7 ), 16 ) );}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using double quotation

```
       drawable.setColor("0xF0" + Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(color)));
```

Comment: That won't compile

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help. I solved it like this:

```
 drawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F0" + color));
```